# Is the statement where Makruh is mentioned unrestrictedly means Makruh Tahriman found in Fath Bab Al-Inayah?

Tags: reference-request, hanafi, books, makruh

From [this website](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa/8505):

> In the Hanafi Madhab, when the word Makruh or Karaha is mentioned unrestrictedly (mutlaqan), it usually refers to Makruh Tahriman. This is a general principle for which there are exceptions.

They mention the whole post was primarily based on [Fath bab al-Inayah](https://attahawi.files.wordpress.com/2009/12/fath-bab-al-inayah.pdf).

I'm wondering whether or not this is stated in this book.

**Question:** Is the statement where Makruh is mentioned unrestrictedly means Makruh Tahriman found in Fath Bab Al-Inayah?

<sub>**Note:** I know I provide a reference to the book but I'm not fluent in Arabic so I do not know what it means and could not find an English copy.</sub>